# Rails: turning text form into select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

to be honest, I almost find html forms more straightforward than Rails form helpers. I'm trying to turn this text form into a select box with options Canada, United States, Mexico as strings

```
 <p><%= f.label :country %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :country %></p>
```

Because the model is already represented in the block variable "f", I'm not sure how to alter the syntax because the model is usually represented first in the complicated hash of variables and options http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Can anyone show me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<%= f.select :country, [["Canada", "Canada"], ["Mexico", "Mexico"], ["United States", "United States"]] %>
```

You can read more in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) & [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select). As @ka8751 says, though, if you have a `Country` model, [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) makes this far easier:

```
<%= f.collection_select :country, Country.all, :id, :name %>
```

where `:id` is used for the actual `value` of the `<option>` tag and `:name` is used for what is displayed.

If you *don't* have a `Country` model, you should consider one for the sake of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: I'm adding it as a field on the User model for devise. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @Michael It shouldn't, no. I don't have any experience with Devise, but a model attribute is still a model attribute, though, devise or not. Were there any problems with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistake here: you are using `text_field` instead of `select` method. To make select box I would recommend you to use `collection_select` method:

```
<%= f.collection_select :country, Country.all, :id, :name %>
```

Also there is a wonderful gem `country_select` to solve your problem and it used by formtastic [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) which I also recommend you to use for building your forms.

Comment: They didn't make a mistake, they're trying to change what they have to use a `<select>`. Further, you're assuming the user has a `Country` model.

Comment: Thanks for response. And yes I didn't say that it is assuming Country mode is exist. If you don't have country model you are able to use: `f.collection_select :country, [['Country 1', 'Country 1'], ['Country 2', 'Country 2']], :to_s, :to_s`

Comment: Actually, that would have to just be `['Country 1', 'Country 2']`, else `to_s` would be called on an array.

Comment: Actually, no the model is a User. It's just being added to the devise registration form.

Comment: Andrew Marshall, `to_s ` would be called for array's item!